# How can I set a minimum required version to my Excel Add-In?

Tags: excel, office-js

In my manifest file I have the following code:

```
<Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.2">
        <Set Name="ExcelApi" MinVersion="1.2"/>
    </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

But it doesn't work, the manifest file is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Requirements>` element has to be between the `<Hosts>` and `<DefaultSettings>` elements within a parent `<OfficeApp>` element.

We have not done a good job of documenting the required sequence. In the meantime, you can see the [OfficeAppManifestV1_1](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/overview/schemas/taskpane/OfficeAppManifestV1_1.xsd).